# Dynamic Texturing using websocket data in three.js

Tags: websocket, three.js, textures

I'm currently trying to implement a virtual desktop (browser) viewer for my phone using chrome's API where captureVisibleTab() is used with mutationObservers to listen to changes in the DOM, and these changes are then transmitted via websockets. To display this, I'm attempting to create a simple rectangle and with the browser feed displayed through textures, however, I'm struggling to find documentation within three.js that will dynamically interpret and display new pictures as textures, and I realize that needsUpdate flag will need to be set to true. So I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions on how to approach this? Do I need to perhaps use loaders?

Answer (score 0):

Could you assign the image data to a canvas and use that as a texture?

Something like [Is it possible to use a 2d canvas as a texture for a cube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370617/is-it-possible-to-use-a-2d-canvas-as-a-texture-for-a-cube)

Comment: That looks promising, however, my current problem is how to deal with the fact that the image file is constantly changing, and not preset as it's shown in the example. Would this be what loaders are used for? I've been having trouble figuring out their purpose as the three.js documentation for loaders is incomplete.