# Can i use fabric.js and three.js in the same canvas?

Tags: canvas, three.js, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Is it possible to use three.js for 3d drawing and add to fabric.js for 2d drawing to the same canvas?  I just like the way fabric.js handles manipulation and would like to make use of it.  Before I start to experiment, I'm wondering if any one has tried this?  Is it possible?

Comment: No, but depending on your design requirements you could overlay a 3D canvas with a separate 2D canvas -- or visa-versa.

Comment: I have seen this recommendation, but this project will require the 2d canvas (text) to be in the 3d scene.

Answer (score 3):

An alternative approach is to use FabricJS with an off-screen canvas, then use that canvas as a texture (image) source for your on-screen WebGL/tree.js canvas and the polygon you are rendering there.

[Is it possible to use a 2d canvas as a texture for a cube?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370617/is-it-possible-to-use-a-2d-canvas-as-a-texture-for-a-cube)

```
var texture = new THREE.Texture(fabricCanvas);
```

To interact with the FabricJS canvas you would have to convert your mouse coordinate for the WebGL canvas into compatible coordinates for the FabricJS 2D canvas (i.e. inverse 3D matrix conversion on your 3D polygon, or a similar approach. See [this example](https://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Mouse-Click.html) for one way to deal with mouse coordinates in 3D space), then produce mouse events from that conversion and send those to the off-screen canvas.

After changes are made to the FabricJS, force texture update:

```
texture.needsUpdate = true;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't use [both a 2D context and 3D context on the same canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928558/canvas-3d-drawing-using-both-2d-and-3d-context). So it is possible but you'll have to use the [`CanvasRenderer`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Renderers/CanvasRenderer) with THREE.js. It's slower but Fabric.js uses a 2D context so you'll have to use it if you intend to use both on the same canvas.

Comment: Thanks Mike...I'll check that out.

Comment: @Mullainathan No. Follow the `CanvasRenderer` link and there is sample code there.